# why isn't my Jlabels or Jpanels showing?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jframe, jpanel

i've added a title to my Jframe, and now its blocked everything else, what have I done??

```
public class addressbook
{
public JFrame frame;
public JButton btnadd, btndelete, btnsave, btnprev, btnnext;
public JPanel panel, pTitle;
public JTextField txtname, txtaddress, txthomeno, txtmobno;
public JLabel JlbName , JlbHtn, JlbMtn, JlbAddress, lblTitle;
public addressbook() {


    //sets window
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Address Book");
    frame.setSize(450, 580);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //sets up panel
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    pTitle = new JPanel();
pTitle.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
lblTitle = new JLabel("Bournemouth University Address Book");
pTitle.add(lblTitle);
frame.add(pTitle);



  //Labels
    JlbName = new JLabel("Name:");
    JlbName.setBounds(10, 50, 100, 20);
    panel.add(JlbName);

    JlbHtn = new JLabel("Home Number:");
    JlbHtn.setBounds(10, 90, 150, 20);
    panel.add(JlbHtn);

    JlbMtn = new JLabel("Mobile Number:");
    JlbMtn.setBounds(10, 130, 200, 20);
    panel.add(JlbMtn);

    JlbAddress = new JLabel("Address:");
    JlbAddress.setBounds(10, 170, 250, 20);
    panel.add(JlbAddress);

    //Text Fields
    txtname = new JTextField("Name");
    txtname.setBounds(120, 50, 200, 20);
    panel.add(txtname);

    txthomeno = new JTextField("Home Number");
    txthomeno.setBounds(120, 90, 200, 20);
    panel.add(txthomeno);

    txtmobno = new JTextField("Mob Number");
    txtmobno.setBounds(120, 130, 200, 20);
    panel.add(txtmobno);

    txtaddress = new JTextField("Address");
    txtaddress.setBounds(120, 170, 250, 20);
    panel.add(txtaddress);

    frame.setVisible(true);



    //Buttons && Button Functions
    btnadd = new JButton("Add", new ImageIcon("../files/add.png"));
    btnadd.setBounds(180, 350, 100, 50);
    btnadd.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
   {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
   {

   }});
   panel.add(btnadd);

    btndelete = new JButton("Delete", new ImageIcon("../files/delete2.png"));
    btndelete.setBounds(180, 450, 100, 50);
    btndelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {

    }});
    panel.add(btndelete);

    btnsave = new JButton("Save", new ImageIcon("../files/save.png"));
    btnsave.setBounds(180, 400, 100, 50);
    btnsave.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {

    }});
    panel.add(btnsave);

    btnprev = new JButton(new ImageIcon("../files/left.png"));
    btnprev.setBounds(180, 300, 100, 50);
    btnprev.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {

    }});
    panel.add(btnprev);

    btnnext = new JButton(new ImageIcon("../files/right.png"));
    btnnext.setBounds(180, 250, 100, 50);
    btnnext.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {

    }});
    panel.add(btnnext);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    panel.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Classnames should be uppercase; Does this code run in the EDT? Because it should.

Comment: What does "its blocked everything else" mean?

Comment: its only showing my title panel, everything else isn't showing

Comment: You should also try to pick a variable naming convention and stick to it. Right now you have all lowercase, camel case (with the first letter as upper and lower case), and aren't consistent with if you want the J there for your abbreviation for a Jlabel.

Comment: yeah I know that, but at the moment my problem is that none of the Jlabels or Jpanels are showing up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the label to the panel, don't create a new Panel for it

```
lblTitle = new JLabel("Bournemouth University Address Book");
lblTitle.setBounds(100, 0, 400, 20);
panel.add(lblTitle);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using a [LayoutManager](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html) on purpose (and it looks that way) make sure that you set a location and a size for your component.

```
pTitle.setLocation(100, 100);
pTitle.setSize(100, 100);
```

But you should rather remove this line

```
panel.setLayout(null);
```

and replace it with something like this:

```
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Also, don’t forget to add your `pTitle` to `panel`.

Comment: i'm sorry im not following, i'm a novice at this

Comment: Then follow Erkan’s advice and read a tutorial, please: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/start/compile.html

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your JPanel `pTitle` to `frame.getContentPane()` or to the JPanel `panel`

**Edit**

Instead of

```
frame.add(pTitle);
```

do:

```
frame.getContentPanel().add(pTitle);
```

If this very quick fix doesn't help, stick with the answer you've already accepted.

Comment: can you explain, i'm really sorry but i really dont understand java

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a LayoutManager for your frame:

```
frame = new JFrame();    
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(FooLayout());
```